# Power Automate: Compare two SharePoint lists and find what's missing

Tags: power-automate

I have two SharePoint lists List A: employee ID and employee email, List B: employee ID and Date of Acknowledgement.  I would like to use Power automate to compare the two lists and find out who on list A is not on list B. Then I would like to send the people on list A who are not on list B an email to please acknowledge.

I followed these instructions on YouTube https://youtu.be/G0GEdtn83pU?si=SFqROohx4zBd5xhu and https://www.damobird365.com/efficien-union-except-and-intersect-great-method/, and am able to create an array of people who are not on list B varPending (Value EmployeeID,Email) , but I can't figure out how to split the variable so that I can send emails to the people not on the list.